# Undefined array key "inventory_source"

Tags: magento2, inventory, multi-source-inventory

I'm getting the following error while running  the setup upgrade command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Warning: Undefined array key "inventory_source" in /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 153 Setup:upgrade stalls with this error and magento goes off line Appreciate

This error is showing after MSI inventory management is uninstalled.

Can anyone help me?